# Accessing contents of a file in a web-application without uploading

Tags: javascript, web-applications, file-upload, html

As far as I can tell, it is impossible to access the content of files on the user's computer in a web application without first uploading to the server, then re-downloading to user, unless some sort of plug-in is used. (Flash, etc.) Ideally, the user would upload the file directly to localstorage and then scripts would have a chance to process/display/validate/filter without the user having to wait on an upload.

Are there any features in upcoming web standards such as html5 that will allow this? If not, why has there been no effort to make this possible, and how can I work around it without getting stuck with plugins?

**EDIT:** ***DO NOT assume that I want to let JavaScript access arbitrary files on the hard drive without any user intervention.*** We already have the ability to prompt the user for a file and upload it, I only want the ability to prompt the user for a file to be loaded into the browser's memory. **I was only hoping HTML5 would have support for something you can already do with both Flash and Java applets.**

Comment: See Raymond Chen's [When People Ask for Security Holes as Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/tags/when+people+ask+for+security+holes+as+features/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't the File API ( http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ ) do that ?

It's implemented in Firefox 3.6 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications )

According to http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/html5-status-chrome.html it is supported in chrome.

Comment: Support for this has changed over the years.  File Reader can do more of what most people need for getting contents of a file.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in HTML 5 (or 6, 7, ...) depends on what a diverse group of vendors with competing agendas think the new HTML version should or should not do... it is [designed by committee](http://winstonlawrence.com/notebook/2010/html5-giving-birth-by-committee/).

Giving a web page that you create permission to access resources (e.g. files) on your computer creates a very large security hole (would you like my web page to read your emails and home banking files?)

It's very unlikely that a committee will agree to standardize on a feature that creates a security risk, given that only one browser on one device/platform needs to poorly implement that standard to open [Pandora's Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora's_box) to hackers.

Individual vendors (the people that make plugins) don't have to get a bunch of other companies to agree on a feature.  They just implement it, and users get to decide if they trust it enough to install it.  Microsoft's first attempt at this was a [major security disaster](http://www.google.com/search?q=activex+security+issue).

Answer (score 1):

Like Raul and Eric pointed out, there is a significant trust issue involved, and requiring people to give code they don't know access to their hard drives will not make your site popular.

You are probably stuck with choosing between plugins or browser specific features/addons for a long time.

That said, you can do cool things by just making the best of this situation. One approach I've used several times is to have an invisible plugin (Applet in my case) present on a web page, but control it entirely via JavaScript, giving the web app a very "natural" look and feel.

Another approach is progressive enhancement of some sort - providing an enhanced experience for users who have the required plugin installed and opt to use it. I've experimented with this on sites such as http://www.pdfcombine.com - users who don't have the Java plugin installed get to merge PDF files by uploading them to a server and downloading the merged file, whereas users with the Java plugin are given the option to do it all locally with the Applet.