# Get uploaded file content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to upload a user file and pass its content to a textarea using javascript/jquery?

Comment: It's possible but it won't just require client side code. You need to do stuff at server side too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing contents of a file in a web-application without uploading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034845/accessing-contents-of-a-file-in-a-web-application-without-uploading)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible.

1. Upload the file using post to a url for ex. http://a.b/c
2. Read the file at the server side. Lets suppose you have another URL such as http://a.b/getcontent which reads that file at server side & replies with the content.
3. You send an AJAX request to /getcontent URL and receive the reply.
4. Change the HTML using javascript accordingly.

Comment: +1 that's the correct answer - no pure JS solution, just with a server side help

Comment: Will there ever be pure JS solution? I am interested in only uploading, parsing and  embedding the data from file directly on the page without server-side meddling (in theory server-side is not needed here)...

Comment: Actually you can read a file client side prior to uploading it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this open-project should be all you need.
It's a JQuery-based file uploader. 
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Once you have it uploaded, store it in wherever you store it (i.e. your database) and get it back via a JQuery ajax query.